# pthread not to inherit definer and includes file

Tags: php, pthreads

Is there any possibilities that could not inherit includes files and definer variable in pthread run method? I have tried with `PTHREADS_INHERIT_NONE` but it seems 
 not working. We have used below code .

```
$domain_root='/home/user/abc';
define('DIR_FS_DOMAIN_ROOT', $domain_root);
class NEWThread extends Thread{
    public function __construct()
    {

   }
    public function run()
    {
         $this->html=DIR_FS_DOMAIN_ROOT;
    }
}
$th=new NEWThread(PTHREADS_INHERIT_NONE);
$th->start();
$th->join();
echo $th->html;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PTHREADS_INHERIT_NONE in wrong place. It should use with start method.

```
$domain_root='/home/user/abc';
define('DIR_FS_DOMAIN_ROOT', $domain_root);
class NEWThread extends Thread{
   public function __construct(){
   }
  public function run(){
     $this->html=DIR_FS_DOMAIN_ROOT;
  }
}
$th=new NEWThread();
$th->start(PTHREADS_INHERIT_NONE);
$th->join();
echo $th->html;
```